# Safari Browser Renders SVG Twice after Rotate Transformation

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, safari

While rendering a toggle box in the browser, clicking on the headline should open/close the toggle content area and also rotate the SVG arrow 180deg. This works properly in all browsers except Safari (both mobile and desktop). It appears to render both versions of the SVG arrow at the same time.

```
i {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: 12px;
}

.active i { 
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); /* Safari 3-8 */
}
```

Sample code available in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e6gbdkaL/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhat related to SVG transformation.

You'll want to define `transform-origin` and apply rotation to the `<g>` element.

```
i > svg > g {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.active i > svg > g {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

See this fiddle for a workable solution: https://jsfiddle.net/df75g16k/

Answer (score 0):

Discovered I also needed to fiddle with the width/height, padding, and z-index to fix where Safari was cutting off the edge of the SVG after the rotate transformation.

```
i {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background: transparent;
    z-index: 25;
    padding: 0 12px;
    margin-right: 12px;

    > svg { width: 24px; }

    > svg > g {
        min-width: 24px;
        transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}

.active i > svg > g {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```